# Laravel Nova: Modify value (muliply) before saving to database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I am using Laravel Nova to administrate my project. However, I save certain values in my database like percentages or prices as `x*100`. Why I am doing this? Because when saving numbers `*100` I can store them as `int` instead of `double` or `float`.

However, this leads to the problem that I am seeing the number which is saved and multiplied by 100 in the database on my Laravel Nova Admin dashboard. I mean I can bypass that by using `resolveUsing` or `displayUsing` ([read here](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#field-resolution-formatting)). Then e.g. `1530` will be presented as `15,30` when diving by `100` which is correct.

The only problem with this is when typing 100 in the percentage field e.g. it also gets saved as 100 and not as 10000 (100*100). Does anybody knows how I can implement this?

I also tried to use eloquent observers. But this doesn't work because I end up in a infinity loop.

Kind regards and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use model accessor and mutator.
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

If you will use mutator and accesor, you should remove `resolveUsing` and `displayUsing` in your resource fields declaration.

```
public function setAmountAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['amount'] = $value * 100;
}

public function getAmountAttribute($value)
{
    return $value / 100;
}
```